# Highstock shared tooltip multiple series - show data for line when not on point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/zv6ymqpL/3/

```
series: [{
     type: 'column',
     name: 'Columns',
     data: data
}, {
     type: 'line',
     name: 'Lines',
     data: line,
     step: true
}]
```

When hovering over the chart the tooltip will display both series or just the columns this is because the column series has a higher resolution (1 hour) compared to the line (2 hour).

The chart I'm using has a line series with step enabled, I want the tooltip when hovering over a data point to include the current step value (as it's all the same value from the last point until the next point).

Is this possible to do in Highstock?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a formatter to calculate the values in the expanded step as to account for the lower resolution.

docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter

Example:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>1 USD = ' + this.y + ' EUR';
            });

            return s;
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

});

P.S. - If I could see a sample data set (In JSON), I'll be able to calculate this.

Comment: The jsfiddle has a random generated dataset, similar to the one I'm using. Column series which has a 5 min resolution, then a line series that has a 1 hour resolution.

Comment: Based on a simple one-dimensional array object, I came up with this loop to get you started: `formatter: function () {
                
var s;
                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    s =  this.series.data.indexOf(this.point) + this.series.data.indexOf(this.point -1) + this.series.data.indexOf(this.point - 2);
                });

                return s;
            }
        },`